# Transformation to choose datatable based on value in separate table

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I have three tables (Oracle source), lets call them tables 1, 2, and 3.

I would like to check a boolean field in table 1, and if it is T I want only data from table 2, and if it is F, I want only table 3.

Which transformation would be the most efficient for doing so, and how would I go about implementing it?

I'm experimenting with the Filter, Java, and Expression transformations, but if the expressions are checking on a row-by-row basis, then it seems like overkill for the expression to run on every row instead of just checking once and using the appropriate table.

Both tables 2 and 3 have a field with the same name, and I want that field for just one of the tables, based on the condition.

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz They have a similar structure, but not the same. Both tables 2 and 3 have a field with the same name, and I want that field for just one of the tables, based on the condition. I don't really have a preference for number of mappings, whichever is faster if it makes a difference, if I had to choose I would say one mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a mapping similar to the following diagram:

```
src_TABLE2 --> sq_TABLE2 --|
                           |--> union --> (further processing)
src_TABLE3 --> sq_TABLE3 --|
```

and use the following `Source Filter` conditions<sup>*</sup> in the source qualifiers:

```
-- for sq_TABLE2
'T' = ( SELECT FLAG FROM TABLE1 )

-- for sq_TABLE3
'F' = ( SELECT FLAG FROM TABLE1 )
```

There are two source tables in the mapping and the union transformation merges data from these two pipelines. However, because of the filtering conditions at any given time data will be retrieved only from one of the source tables.

<sub>* `Source Filter` is an attribute on the *Properties* tab of a source qualifier. The condition you set here is appended to the `WHERE` clause of the `SELECT` statement that is sent to the database.</sub>

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you used/setup the conditions on the source qualifiers?

Comment: So you're saying I should put a "SELECT FLAG FROM TABLE1" in the source qualifier, without any mappings from TABLE1 to TABLE2/TABLE3? Meaning I don't have to link the two qualifiers/sources?

Comment: @JWiley Yes, you should put this query (along with `= 'T'` or `= 'F'`) in the source qualifiers for TABLE2 and TABLE3. The mapping doesn't need to contain a source qualifier for TABLE1, you don't need a source definition for this table at all. You can put any condition (with complicated nested `SELECT` statements referencing any table or schema you need). As long as the resulting query - `SELECT ports FROM sq_table WHERE source_filter` - is valid, it will be sent to the database and executed. Did you try to implement it? Did you try into any problem?

Comment: @JWiley Test it yourself - take any working mapping, put `0 = 1` into the *Source Filter* property of its source qualifier, refresh the session and run it. No rows will be retrieved from the database.

Comment: I have, I just wanted a clarification. My requirements changed several times since the posting, so I was still working out how to apply it.